# How to initialize, create matrix and then print with using structure

Tags: c, matrix, structure

I want to create 2D array using structure and read from user, then display it. But I can't find out what's wrong with this.
/Sorry guys.First, I want it to read a matrix elements from user, then I want to display whole matrix. But it doesn't print properly, it prints address of elements. Why is it printing address, not value? /
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    struct Matrix {
      int n,m;
      int a[100][100];
    }array;
    int main() {
      struct Matrix *p;
      int i,j;
      p = malloc(sizeof(array));
      scanf("%d%d", &p->n, &p->m);
      for (i = 0;i < p->n;i++)
        for (j = 0;j < p->m;j++)

          scanf("%d", p->a[i][j]);
      for (i = 0;i < p->n;i++){

        for (j = 0;j < p->m;j++)

          printf("%d ", (p->a[i][j]));
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
```

Comment: What happens for you to say that it's not working, and that something's wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason for the *variable declaration* of `array`? Is it supposed to be a `typedef`?

Comment: What did you enter?  What was the result?

Comment: Telmen Munkhdalai,  Please edit your question to include why you belive that something's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `scanf("%d", p->a[i][j]);` to `scanf("%d", &p->a[i][j]);`.  Better to check the result of `scanf()` to ensure code received the expected data.

   ```
   if (scanf("%d", &p->a[i][j]) != 1) Oops();
   ```
2. Enable all warning on your compiler.  This problem popped up right away.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   struct Matrix {
       int n, m;
       int a[100][100];
   } array;

   int main() {
       struct Matrix *p;
       int i, j;
       p = malloc(sizeof(array));
       scanf("%d%d", &p->n, &p->m);
       for (i = 0; i < p->n; i++)
           for (j = 0; j < p->m; j++) {
               // scanf("%d", p->a[i][j]);
               scanf("%d", &p->a[i][j]);
           }
       for (i = 0; i < p->n; i++) {
           for (j = 0; j < p->m; j++)
               printf("%d ", (p->a[i][j]));
           printf("\n");
       }
   }
   ```